# Divide last row in each row of my columns

Tags: r, row, divide

This is my dataframe:

```
    Deta <- c("2010-01-29" , "2015-01-29", "2017-01-30")
    v <- c(5.1, 3, 4)
    a <- c(4.3, 2, 6)
    z <- data.frame(Deta,v,a)
```

I want for columns v and a in each row this formule (last row / row -1). Example ( 4 / 5.1 -1)  Could help me ?

I use this `mutate_at(-1, c(z[last(z)])/z-1)` but i have an error

This is the output:

```
    Date           a         v
    2010-01-29  -0.21569  0.3953
    2015-01-29  0.33333   2.0000
    2017-01-30  0.00000   0.00000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use :

```
library(dplyr)
z %>%  mutate_at(-1, ~last(.)/. - 1)
#Can also use 
#z %>%  mutate_at(vars(v, a), ~last(.)/. - 1)
```

Or in base R :

```
z[-1] <- lapply(z[-1], function(x) x[length(x)]/x - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(z)[, (2:ncol(z)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) last(x)/x - 1), .SDcols = -1]
z
#         Deta          v         a
#1: 2010-01-29 -0.2156863 0.3953488
#2: 2015-01-29  0.3333333 2.0000000
#3: 2017-01-30  0.0000000 0.0000000
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
z[-1] <-  mapply(`/`, tail(z[-1], 1),  z[-1])-1
```

Or with vectorized

```
z[-1] <- (tail(z[-1], 1)[col(z[-1])]/z[-1] -1)
```

Comment: A vectorized way: `z[3, c("v", "a"), drop = TRUE] / z[,c("v", "a")] - 1`